# How to use nested component in loop Angular?

Tags: angular

I have the following JSON structure that I want to show using component:

```
const rootBlock = {
   id: 1,
   fields: [],
   blocks: [{
      id: 2,
      fields: []
      blocks: []
   }]
} as Block;
```

There is component `BlockComponent`.

```
@Input() block: Block;
```

I want to show all nested component inside one, how to do that using projection?

```
<app-block>
   <app-block></app-block>
</app-block>
```

Comment: so what should show the app block? can you share the HTML template? so I can try to create it.

Comment: Block component has template `<div class="block"><div>id: {{block.id}}</div><div class="nestedBlocks"></div></div>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your app-block component, keep a ng-content outlet

block.component.html

```
<h2>Some text</h2>
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

Using this, whatever you put inside your  tag, they will render, including the same component nested inside.

**Update:**

**block.component.ts**

```
@Input() block: Block;
```

**block.component.html**

```
<div class="block">
  <div> 
    id: {{block.id}}
  </div>
  <ng-container *ngIf="block?.blocks?.length">
    <div class="nestedBlocks" *ngFor="let eachBLock of block.blocks">
       <app-block [block]="eachBLock"></app-block>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

**app.component.html**

```
<app-block [block]="rootBlock"></app-block>
```

Comment: How it looks in templete? Could you extend the answer?

Comment: I have dynamic JSON object it can be a lot of nested blocks

Comment: I have udated the answer. You can try that.

Comment: I need still `<ng-content></ng-content>`?

Comment: No. That should not be required anymore for your case.